# Вставить данные в таблицу

Tags: java, swing, jtable

скажите как я могу вставить числа в `jtable` при нажатии на кнопку "вставить" ? и как я могу их скопировать нажав на кнопку "копировать", которые находятся у меня на панели? пробую добавить так, но не копируется ни ctrl+c, ни нажав на кнопку

```
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    table1 = new JTable(tableModel);
    JMenuItem m;
    m = new JMenuItem("Копировать");
                m.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        final KeyStroke copy = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK, false);
                        table1.registerKeyboardAction(this, "Copy", copy, JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Comment: Нет кода нет вопроса

Comment: @RomanC мне нужно сделать так, чтобы я мог скопировать числа, которые вводятся пользователем в таблицу а потом вставить их в эту же таблицу

Answer (score 0):

Первый вопрос не совсем понятно! но чтобы скопировать текст, можете написать (**java**)

```
botton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("clipboard", "Текст который будеть скопировано");
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Text copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: внимание, есть вы используйте код в Activity вам следует в месте ```view.getContext()``` использовать ```Activity.this``` !

Comment: Понимаете, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы я мог скопировать числа, которые пользователь введёт в таблицу и вставить их потом в другие ячейки. Ваш код это решит?

Comment: Выложи код , мы здесь не экстрасенсы, чтобы узнать что у тебя там под капотом творится!

Comment: Мой код копирует текст в буфер обмена устройства, при нажатии на кнопку и всё!

Comment: я добавил фрагмент кода с которым у меня проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Следующий класс позволяет скопировать/вставить строку в/из буфера обмена.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SystemClipboard
{
    public static void copy(String text)
    {
        Clipboard clipboard = getSystemClipboard();

        clipboard.setContents(new StringSelection(text), null);
    }

    public static void paste() throws AWTException
    {
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    }

    public static String get() throws Exception
    {
        Clipboard systemClipboard = getSystemClipboard();
        DataFlavor dataFlavor = DataFlavor.stringFlavor;

        if (systemClipboard.isDataFlavorAvailable(dataFlavor))
        {
            Object text = systemClipboard.getData(dataFlavor);
            return (String) text;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static Clipboard getSystemClipboard()
    {
        Toolkit defaultToolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Clipboard systemClipboard = defaultToolkit.getSystemClipboard();

        return systemClipboard;
    }
}
```

Чтобы скопировать **SystemClipboard.copy("text");**
чтобы вставить
**SystemClipboard.get()**

Comment: я новичок в java. скажите мне этот класс нужно вставить в слушатель кнопки ?

Comment: Вообще то, если вы не собираетесь использовать тот текст которые хотите скопировать, за пределами своего приложении, вам даже класс не нужен!

Comment: ну да,мне нужно только в пределах программы скопировать и вставить. тогда подскажите пожалуйста, как быть? почему-то мой фрагмент кода не работает

Comment: Код которые вы выложили, ни о чём не говорит, либо выложите весь код, не мучаете нас)) 

Comment: вот, дополнил ещё

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html